# PHP Multidimensional Array - Count Number of Instances

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am struggling a bit with a multidimensional array in PHP.  I am new to PHP so please be aware that I may come across as a bit of a noob.

What I am trying to achieve:  I am using ExpressionEngine as my CMS, with Freeform Pro to record answers to a survey.  The values of the answers are 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.  That all works fine.  Then I am using a SQL query to pull that saved data out of the database.  This is where it starts getting complicated.  I need the average of each question in the survey.  So the logical thing to do (I would think) is to pull the data for each question and put it in an array:

```
$tva_1 = array();
$tva_2 = array();
$tva_3 = array();
$tva_4 = array();

SELECT form_field_259, form_field_260, form_field_261, form_field_262 FROM exp_freeform_form_entries_13 WHERE status='open'

array_push($tva_1, ('{form_field_259}'));
array_push($tva_2, ('{form_field_260}'));
array_push($tva_3, ('{form_field_261}'));
array_push($tva_4, ('{form_field_262}'));
```

Keep in mind that $tva_1 may have 5 variables in it, for example: 2, 4, 3, 1, 4.  The same goes for $tva_2 and so on.

So once I have assigned that data to the various tva_ arrays, I then need to put those four arrays into another array, namely $allNumberArray:

```
$allNumberArray = array($tva_1, $tva_2, $tva_3, $tva_4);
```

So now if I try print_r($allNumberArray); it shows me all the data is there and everything is working as it should.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 3
        )
```

The problem is: I need to count the number of times each rating has been used.  So for example, I can see from the above print_r that 5 is displayed 4 times, 4 is displayed 3 times, 3 is displayed 7 times, etc..  I have tried a count function such as the one below, but that only works in a single dimension array (I think):

```
$userStrongAgree = count(array_filter($allNumberArray, function ($agreementFive) { return $agreementFive == 5; }));
```

I have been stuck on this problem now for a day and a half, and my deadline is tomorrow afternoon, so I am starting to get a bit worried.  I really would appreciate any help or just a pointer in the right direction.

Many thanks

Comment: it seems overcomplicated. could you try to provide datatable example, and expected result table? I really beleive that it could be done just by query request without any transformation after

Comment: Wow, 1 or 2 lines of code loses over 11 lines of loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to push all items into uniquq array and count it with `array_count_values()` :

```
<?php
$array=$allNumberArray; //your Array

$new_arr=array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        array_push($new_arr,$value2);
        }
}
$last_arr=array_count_values($new_arr);
foreach ($last_arr as $key3 => $value3) {
    echo $key3.' is '.$value3.' times<br>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much man, in one copy and paste, you have solved the problem I have been trying fix for days.  And the solution seems way simpler than I was expecting it to be.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.  The index is the value/rating and the value is the count:

```
$count = array_count_values(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array));
```